# POST can't return character string get return 500

Tags: android, python, django

I try testing my server and connect with android client with django.

**My Code:**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
    def first_page(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            return HttpResponse('you are post method')
        elif request.method == 'GET':
            return HttpResponse('you are get method')
```

android client post my server was always **500 response**. and if change the method, and use the if `request.method == 'GET:'` this work.

I'am confused what happen, `POST` method can not use **HttpResponse**?

Update my client error info as blow:

```
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentType(Unknown Source)
```

can anyone help us?

Comment: Did you check what the error actually is? You should see a traceback in the log file, if you're logging errors. Turn on debug if this isn't a production setup to get the django debugger page instead of 500 error.

Comment: Why do you have an emoji in your response string?

Comment: because..use macbook and can input EMOJI it doesn't matter i try coding without EMOJI can not work too @aumo

Comment: Of course you can return a response for a POST request - in fact you MUST return a response. Your problem is elsewhere, so check your logs / your emails / the debugger page, as Lidor said.

Comment: android client get return 500 .. can andoird client get the debugger if I open  django debugger?? My browser use `GET`.. I trying see apache log_error @Lidor@bruno desthuilliers

Comment: Use tools such as [Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) (Chrome) or [RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/restclient/) (Firefox) to make POST requests from your browser. You should also be able to see a log of the traceback of the exception responsible of the 500 error somewhere. Are you running Django with `./manage.py runserver`?

Comment: @aumo product envierment. On Apache2.4. of course on it. and I test already. If I use  my browser access.can use `POST` and get return. but Android client still return 500... confused me ..